# Enable 1GB Huge Pages on ubuntu 20.04 failed using `echo 1 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages`

Tags: kernel, ram

I try to enable 1GB Huge Pages on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 using [echo 1 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx5Cj.png) with the root user account, but I can't write to `/sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages` using the root user account, because there's "No such file or directory" on my Ubuntu Desktop 20.04: How can I resolve this?

Comment: It works for me. Maybe some `hugepage` stuff is not included in your kernel configuration. Do, for example: `grep -i hugepage /boot/config-5.15.0-52-generic` and tell use which kernel you are running.

Comment: 5.15.0-48-generic. CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_TRANSPARANT_HUGEPAGE=y

Comment: Not the latest kernel if that matters.

Comment: @David Didn't matter. Simply no hugepage support